# Is there a method to separate ions from water other than by double displacement precipitation?

Tags: solutions

I'm working on a problem for school where we have to detect Fe<sup>3+</sup>, Ca<sup>2+</sup>, Cl<sup>-</sup>, and SO<sub>4</sub><sup>2-</sup> ions in water, and we have been given AgNO<sub>3</sub>, KSCN, BaCl<sub>2</sub>, and a HC<sub>2</sub>H<sub>3</sub>O<sub>2</sub>/Na<sub>2</sub>C<sub>2</sub>O<sub>4</sub> mixture (all in solution) to do so. We have already determined the ion content by precipitating them out using successive double displacement reactions, but we also have to do it using another method. Is there another way to separate or detect ions in solution?

Comment: There's no need to separate, only detect...

Comment: Can you describe the limits of your problem in more detail? Do you have to actually complete the task with the equipment available to you or do you just have to suggest a way you could do it? If you have access to other stuff, there are many options.

Comment: @ericksonla We have to complete the task, and we don't have access to any other chemicals unless we acquire them ourselves.